# Understanding Time complexity of O(max(m,n))

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity

Can some body given a simple program or algorithm whose Time complexity is O(max(m,n)). I am trying to understand asymptotic notations. I followed some tutorials and understood what they have explained that i.e O(n),  and O(n^2).

But now I want to understand Time complexity for O(max(m,n)) and how it is calculated. 
Please give a sample program or algorithm to demonstrate this.

Comment: What is `max`?  Is it just the higher of m and n?  If that's the case, then it is simply `O(m)` if m is larger than n, or `O(n)` if n is larger than m.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common theorem to prove when studying big-O notation for the first time is that

> Θ(max{m, n}) = Θ(m + n)

In other words, any algorithm whose runtime is O(max{m, n}) also has runtime O(m + n), so any algorithm with this time complexity will fit the bill.

As a specific example of this, consider the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt string-matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), which takes in two strings and returns whether the first string is a substring of the second.  The runtime is Θ(m + n) = Θ(max{m, n}), meaning that the runtime is linear in the length of the longer of the two strings.

I apologize if this doesn't give something that *intuitively* has runtime max{m, n}, but mathematically this does work out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Gray Yep! Fixed. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

The one I can think of is [Python's `izip_longest` function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) :

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>   If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in
>   with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is
>   exhausted.

For example:

```
In [1]: from itertools import zip_longest

In [2]: list(zip_longest([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], ['a', 'b', 'c']))
Out[2]: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, None), (5, None), (6, None), (7, None)]

In [3]: list(zip_longest([1, 2], ['a', 'b', 'c']))
Out[3]: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (None, 'c')]

In [4]: list(zip_longest([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']))
Out[4]: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

It should be clear why this is an `O(max(m, n))` operation and not O(m+n), as far as I know; because when `m > n`, increasing `n` doesn't increase time required.

Comment: Actually Θ(m+n) is the same as Θ(max(m, n)) for reasonable definitions of Θ(...) for multiple variables. If one of n, m dominates the other, the usual reasoning for Θ(some sum) applies. And if n and m are roughly similar, both Θ(n+m) and Θ(max(n, m)) simplify to Θ(2n) (or Θ(2m), it's the same) which is again just Θ(n). That said, I've argued elsewhere that the version with the + is also educational.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest example is

```
for i=0 to max(m,n)
     print 'a'
```

From theory: `O(max(m,n))` is just `O(m+n)`

The "real life" example of `O(max(m,n))` may be the algorithm which for two unsorted arrays of size `m` and `n` respectively - finds the biggest elements of both

Comment: If `O(max(m,n))` is just `O(m+n)`, then why not just say `O(m+n)`?

Comment: They might be emphasizing the max part.  There are lots of ways to describe the order of a given function.  Adding a non-zero constant doesn't change the order, for instance.  Or the base of a log, or etc.

Comment: @Robert as Joel said - the most probable reason is the will to emphasize that if we do the strict cost analysis, than it is actually the max operation, but in `O` notation it does not matter as max(m,n)=THETA (m+n) (these functions are equivalent in the complexity sense), this is an obvious consequence of 1/2(m+n) <= max(m,n) <= m+n <= 2*max(m.n)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best answer to your question is the Robert Harvey's comment. In my opinion, a  good example of an algorithm where that kind of bounding is used is the [`DFS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

I hope, that this will clear your doubts:

DFS examines every vertex and every edge of a graph. Let `n` denotes the number of vertices in the graph and `m` denotes the number of edges in it.

Based on an above observation, you can derive an upper bound for the time complexity of `DFS` as `O(max(n, m))`.

Just notice, that there are graphs for which you cannot bound the time complexity of `DFS` by just `O(n)`. A [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) is an example.

Also, there are graphs for which you cannot bound the time complexity of `DFS` by just `O(m)`. A [null graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_graph) is an example.