# Comparing complexity of O(n+m) and O(max(n,m))

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I had a job interview today.  And was asked about complexity of `std:set_intersection`. When I was answering I mentioned that

*O(n+m)*

is equal to:

*O(max(n,m))*

I was told that this is incorrect. I was unsuccessfully trying  to show equivalence with:

*O(0.5*(n+m))  ≤  O(max(n,m))  ≤  O(n+m)*

My question is: am I really incorrect?

Comment: My understanding matches yours.  Min(m+n) is basically a constant to be disregarded within O notation. But I don't have a reference to prove it.

Comment: This seems to agree with you: http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11704

Comment: This does too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19458485/179850

Comment: You're more knowledgeable than the interviewer, that's all. They were expecting one answer, and you gave another, so they thought you were wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For all *m*, *n* ≥ 0 it is valid that max(*m*, *n*) ≤ *m* + *n* → max(*m*, *n*) in *O*(*m* + *n*), and *m* + *n* ≤ 2max(*m*, *n*) → *m* + *n* in *O*(max(*m*, *n*)).

Thus *O*(max(*m*, *n*)) = *O*(*m* + *n*).

**ADDENDUM**: If *f* belongs *O*(*m* + *n*) then a constant *D* > 0 exists, that *f*(*n*, *m*) < *D* * (*m* + *n*) for *m* and *n* large enough. Thus *f*(*n*, *m*) < 2 *D* * max(*m*, *n*), and *O*(*m* + *n*) must be a subset of *O*(max(*m*, *n*)). The proof of *O*(max(*m*, *n*)) is a subset of *O*(*m* + *n*) is made analogously.

Comment: Can you edit this a bit, I'm getting confused by your use of "≤" and "=>"?  Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem? It's the common meaning of _less or equal_ and _follows_.

Comment: So `=>` is the same as `≥` ?  If you could be consistent with `≤` and `≥` that would be good.

Comment: No, _A_ => _B_ means _B_ follows from _A_., while _a_ ≥ _b_ means _a_ is (numerical) greater or equal than _b_.

Comment: Yeah that was the other consideration.  Thanks for the clarification.  Unfortunately the OP uses <= as ≤ so I was confused.

Comment: you could use → for follows

Comment: I have replaced the arrows.

Comment: @macmoonshine, your reasoning "Thus O(max(m, n)) = O(m + n)." is not correct ,the only thing you prove above is that F1=max(n,m) belongs in the Set (m+n) =Set1  and also F2=m+n belongs in the set O(max(m,n))= Set2. So you prove that F1 belongs to a Set1 and F2 belongs to a Set2. O(max(m, n)) = O(m + n)  means Set1 equals Set2 which means EVERY Function belongs in Set1 belongs also in Set2 and vice versa . So your reasoning-syllogism does not proves the set equality which is the goal!

Comment: The proof is correct. I implied the common fact that if _f_ in _O_ ( _g_ ) and _g_ in _O_ ( _f_ ), than _O_ ( _g_ ) = _O_ ( _f_ ).

Comment: You haven't proved that part you only showed that f in O ( g ) and g in O ( f ) but you need a proof for O(g) = O(f) and this is what was asked! I didn't say your proof is wrong but it IS NOT PROVING WHAT ASKED!

Comment: Have you seen the addendum?

Comment: Also there is no "common fact" you just considered  as fact the most significant part of the proof, this is wrong!

Comment: The addendum sketches a proof for the equality of the sets by showing that each set is a subset of the other one. What do you not understand, or what you think is missing in the addendum? BTW: What is the difference between _not correct_ and _wrong_?

Comment: The addendum is ok (in fact if you look in my answer I had already given this proof ) I just didn't see when writing the last comment. There is no difference between no correct  and wrong why your asking??

Comment: @coder: I just asked because of usage of _is not correct_ and _is wrong_. I wasn't sure, if I have understood you right.

Answer (score 8):

Well you have  totally right about O(n+m) is equal to O(max(n,m)),even more precise we can prove Θ(n+m)=Θ(max(n,m) which is more tight and proves your sentence. The mathematical proof is (for both big-O and Θ) very simple and easy to understand with common sense. So since we have a `mathematical proof` which is a way to say something but in a more well defined and strict way which `doesn't leaves any ambiguity`.

Though you was (wrongly) told that this is incorrect because if we want to be very precise this is not the appropriate - mathematical way to express that order of max(m,n) is same as m+n. You used the words "is equal" referring to big-O notation but what is the definition of big-O notation?

> It is referred to `Sets`. Saying max(n+m) belongs to O(m+n) is the
>   most correct way and vice versa m+n belongs to O(max(m,n)). In big O
>   notation is commonly used and accepted to say m+n = O(max(n,m)).

The problem caused is that you didn't try to refer to the order of a function like f is O(g) but you tried to compare Sets O(f) and O(g).But proving two infinite  sets are equal is not easy (and that may confused the interviewer).

We can say Sets A and B are identical(or equal) when contain same elements (we do not try to compare but instead refer to elements they contain so they must be **finite**). And  even identification can't be easily applied when talking about  Big O Sets.

> Big O of F is used to notate that we are talking about the Set that
>   contains all functions with order greater  or equal than F. How many
>   functions are there??

```
Infinite since F+c is contained and c can take infinite values.
```

> How could you say two different  Sets are identical(or equal) when they are
>   infinite ,well it is not that simple.

```
So I understand what you are thinking that n+m and max(n,m) have same 
order but **the right way to express that** is by saying n+m is    
O(max(n,m)) and max(n,m)is O(m+n) ( O(m+n) is equal to O(max(m,n)) 
may better requires a proof).
```

One more thing, we said that these functions have same order and this is absolutely mathematically correct but when trying to do optimization of an algorithm and you may need to take into account some lower order factors  then maybe they give you slightly different results but the asymptotic behavior is proved to be the same.

> ***CONCLUSION***

As you can read in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) (and in all cs courses in every university or in every algorithm book) Big O/θ/Ω/ω/ο notations `helps us compare functions` and find their order of growth and not for Sets of Functions and this is why you were told you were wrong. Though  is  easy to say O(n^2) is subset of O(n) it is very difficult to compare infinite to say if two sets are identical. Cantor have worked on categorizing infinite sets, for example we know that  natural numbers are countable infinite and real numbers are uncountable infinite so real numbers are more than natural numbers even though both are infinite. It is getting very complicating when trying t order and categorize infinite sets and this would be more of a research in maths than a way of comparing functions.

---

**UPDATE**

It turns out you could simply prove O(n+m) equals to O(max(n,m)):

for every function F which belongs to O(n+m) this means that there are constant c and k such:

```
 F <= c(n+m) for every n>=k and m>=k
```

then also stands:

```
 F <= c(n+m)<= 2c*max(n,m)
```

so F belongs to O(max(n,m)) and as a result  O(m+n) is subset of O(max(n,m)).
Now consider F belongs to O(max(n,m)) then there are constants c and k such:

```
 F <= c*max(n+m) for every n>=k and m>=k
```

and we also have:

```
F <= c*max(n+m)<=2c(m+n) for every n>=k and m>=k
```

so there is c'=2c and with  same k by definition: F is O(m+n) and as a result O(max(n,m)) is subset of O(n+m). Because we proved  O(m+n) is subset of O(max(n,m)) we proved that **O(max(m,n)) and O(m+n) are equal** **and this mathematical proof proves you had totally right without any doubt.**

Finally note that **proving that m+n is O(max(n,m)) and max(n,m) is O(m+n) doesn't proves immediately that sets are equal** (we need a proof for that) as your saying it just proves that functions have same order but we didn't examine the sets. Though it is easy to see (in general case) that if **f is O(g) and g is O(F)** then you can easily **prove in that case the big O sets equality** like we did in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

We'll show by rigorous Big-O analysis that you are indeed correct, *given one possible choice of parameter of growth* in your analysis. However, this does not necessarily mean that the viewpoint of the interviewer is incorrect, rather that his/her choice of parameter of growth differs. His/her prompt that your answer was outright incorrect, however, is questionable: you've possibly simply used two slightly different approaches to analyzing the asymptotic complexity of `std::set_intersection`, both leading to the general consensus that the algorithm runs in linear time.

---

#### Preparations

Lets start by looking at the reference of `std::set_intersection` at cppreference (**emphasis mine**)

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

> *Parameters*
>
> `first1`, `last1` -   the first range of elements to examine
>
> `first2`, `last2` -   the second range of elements to examine
>
> *Complexity*
>
> **At most** `2·(N1+N2-1)` comparisons, where
>
> ```
> N1 = std::distance(first1, last1)
> N2 = std::distance(first2, last2)
> ```

[`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) itself is naturally linear (worst case: no random access)

> `std::distance`
>
> ...
>
> Returns the number of elements between `first` and `last`.

We'll proceed to briefly recall the basic of Big-O notation.

---

#### Big-O notation

We loosely state the definition of a function or algorithm `f` being in `O(g(n))` (to be picky, `O(g(n))` being a *set of functions*, hence `f ∈ O(...)`, rather than the commonly misused `f(n) ∈ O(...)`).

> If a function `f` is *in* `O(g(n))`, then `c · g(n)` is an upper
>   bound on `f(n)`, for **some non-negative constant `c`** such that `f(n) ≤ c · g(n)`
>   holds, **for sufficiently large `n`** (i.e. , `n ≥ n0` for some constant
>   `n0`).

Hence, to show that `f ∈ O(g(n))`, we need to find a set of (non-negative) constants `(c, n0)` that fulfils

```
f(n) ≤ c · g(n), for all n ≥ n0,                                (+)
```

We note, however, that this set **is not unique**; the problem of finding the constants `(c, n0)` such that (+) holds is *degenerate*. In fact, if any such pair of constants exists, there will exist an infinite amount of different such pairs.

We proceed with the Big-O analysis of `std::set_intersection`, based on the already known worst case number of comparisons of the algorithm (we'll consider one such comparison a *basic operation*).

---

#### Applying Big-O asymptotic analysis to the `set_intersection` example

Now consider two ranges of elements, say `range1` and `range2`, and assume that the number of elements contained in these two ranges are `m` and `n`, respectively.

- Note! Already at this initial stage of the analys do we *make a choice*: we choose to study the problem in terms of two different *parameters of growth* (or rather, focusing on the largest one of these two). As we shall see ahead, this will lead to the same asymptotic complexity as the one stated by the OP. However, we could just as well choose to let `k = m+n` be the parameter of choice: we would still conclude that `std::set_intersection` is of linear-time complexity, but rather in terms of `k` (which is `m+n` **which is not** `max(m, n)`) than the largest of `m` and `n`. These are simply the preconditions we freely choose to set prior to proceeding with our Big-O notation/asymptotic analysis, and it's quite possibly that the interviewer had a preference of choosing to analyze the complexity using `k` as parameter of growth rather than the largest of its two components.

Now, from above we know that as worst case, `std::set_intersection` will run `2 · (m + n - 1)` comparisons/basic operations. Let

```
h(n, m) = 2 · (m + n - 1)
```

Since the goal is to find an expression of the asymptotic complexity in terms of Big-O (upper bound), we may, without loss of generality, assume that `n > m`, and define

```
f(n) = 2 · (n + n - 1) = 4n - 2 > h(n,m)                         (*)
```

We proceed to analyze the asymptotic complexity of `f(n)`, in terms of Big-O notation. Let

```
g(n) = n
```

and note that

```
f(n) = 4n - 2 < 4n = 4 · g(n)
```

Now (choose to) let `c = 4` and `n0 = 1`, and we can state the fact that:

```
f(n) < 4 · g(n) = c · g(n), for all n ≥ n0,                      (**)
```

Given `(**)`, we know from `(+)` that we've now shown that

```
f ∈ O(g(n)) = O(n)
```

Furthermore, since `(*) holds, naturally

```
h ∈ O(g(n)) = O(n), assuming n > m                               (i)
```

holds.

If we switch our initial assumption and assume that `m > n`, re-tracing the analysis above will, conversely, yield the similar result

```
h ∈ O(g(m)) = O(m), assuming m > n                                (ii)
```

---

#### Conclusion

Hence, given two ranges `range1` and `range2` holding `m` and `n` elements, respectively, we've shown that the asymptotic complexity of `std::set_intersection` applied two these two ranges is indeed

> ```
> O(max(m, n))
> ```

where we're chosen the largest of `m` and `n` as the parameter of growth of our analysis.

This is, however, not really valid annotation (at least not common) when speaking about Big-O notation. When we use Big-O notation to describe the asymptotic complexity of some algorithm or function, we do so with regard to some single parameter of growth (not two of them).

Rather than answering that the complexity is `O(max(m, n))` we may, without loss of generality, assume that `n` describes the number of elements in the range *with the most elements*, and given that assumption, simply state than an upper bound for the asymptotic complexity of `std::set_intersection` is `O(n)` (linear time).

---

A speculation as to the interview feedback: as mentioned above, it's possible that the interviewer simply had a firm view that the Big-O notation/asymptotic analysis should've been based on `k = m+n` as parameter of growth rather than the largest of its two components. Another possibility could, naturally, be that the interviewer simply confusingly queried about the worst case of actual *number of comparisons* of `std::set_intersection`, while mixing this with the separate matter of Big-O notation and asymptotic complexity.

---

#### Final remarks

Finally note that the analysis of worst case complexity of `std::set_intersect` is not at all representative for the commonly studied non-ordered set intersection problem: the former is applied to ranges that are already sorted (see quote from Boost's `set_intersection` below: the origin of `std::set_intersection`), whereas in the latter, we study the computation of the intersection of non-ordered collections.

- [Boost: `set_intersection`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/set/set_intersection.html)

> *Description*
>
> `set_intersection` constructs a sorted range that is the intersection
>   of the **sorted** ranges `rng1` and `rng2`. The return value is the
>   end of the output range.

As an example of the latter, the `Intersection` set method of Python applies to non-ordered collections, and is applied to say sets `s` and `t`, [it has an average case and a worst-case complexity of `O(min(len(s), len(t))` and `O(len(s) * len(t))`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), respectively. The huge difference between average and worst case in this implementation stems from the fact that hash based solutions generally works very well in practice, but can, for some applications, theoretically have a very poor worst-case performance.

For additional details of the latter problem, see e.g.

- [Intersection of two unsorted sets or lists @ SE-CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/23757/intersection-of-two-unsorted-sets-or-lists)